# A way to challenge not constructive and off-topic closure of the question

Tags: support, closed-questions

Is there any way to dispute or challenge a question being closed?

I have found over Stack Overflow many times questions that people want the answers to but get marked as non-constructive or off-topic. Never before have I put much thought behind this until one of my own questions was noted as off topic, noted being outside scope defined in the FAQ.

While the FAQ specifically states "a software algorithm" as one of the topics on Stack Overflow, and while I was not asking about a specific algorithm, I was looking for an algorithm. While I don't care about my question specifically, this is a community site where the community up-votes and favorites the questions it would like to have answered. If this is true, there should be the ability to cancel, negate, or dispute a questions state by reputation.

To make this clear, I am NOT saying that my question could be off topic since I asked such a generalized question but am more interesting in knowing why and how further disputes can be handled.

[Algorithm for Image Sampling for Polygonal Representation using Canvas and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772626/image-sampling-for-polygonal-representation-using-canvas-and-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to dispute a closure:

- If you have more than 3,000 reputation you can simply vote to re-open,
- If you have more than 15 reputation you can flag the question for moderation attention and ask the moderators to review the question and re-open it (assuming they agree it's on topic),
- Regardless of reputation you can always post a question about the closure here on Meta.

Your first instinct, however, should always be to try and improve the question. If there are comments asking for clarifications, respond to them by updating your question and clarifying. If there are answers that somehow miss the point of your question, then update it to make the core question clearer.

If there's absolutely nothing that helps you understand what's wrong with the question, don't give up. Take 5 minutes to improve its spelling and grammar and perhaps coming up with a more descriptive title and a better set of tags. Even the slightest improvement might count, and the effort will certainly be appreciated even if the question doesn't get re-opened.

Closed questions that get edited (significantly) after they were closed automatically enter a re-open review queue that's available to users who can vote to re-open. If the closure was incorrect *or* your edit improved the question to the point that it should be re-opened, it will, soon enough.

Lastly, if all else fails, there's always [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (available to users with more than 20 reputation). Find a chat room with a topic relevant to your question and ask the room's crowd for help understanding why the question was closed and what you can do to get it re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

If a question gets closed you can argue with a comment why that is wrong in your opinion.

If you have [enough reputatio](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)n you can also *vote to reopen*.

Your question BTW is a *give me the code* question. You don't show any effort and are just asking for a solution. That is *not a real question* IMO.

[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is a great article to start with before asking.

Comment: I was not looking for code, but I can see your point, I just had searched online much and was looking for a place to start with image sampling and reduction. That being said, I thank you for a point to that link over reputation to close, that was what I was looking for.